# Easiest way to save data in savedInstanceState when managing an adapter(viewpager)

Tags: android

I'm working with an adapter(viewpager) and when the app changes orientation it loses its information. Which is the easiest way to conserve this information? I was going to use savedInstanceState inside the adapter but it doesn't recognise it.

Comment: Could you please show us what you have so far, what you've tried, and what your saving?

Comment: I have some layouts where there're edittext managed by Viewpager. If I change the orientation of the phone it loses information. I know I have to save them before but I can't use savedInstanceState  inside the adapter. I have thougth in: create a plain text, create a little database, refresh every x seconds from the class that creates the adapter and retrieve info from variables but I think those things are so complex for so silly operation

Comment: It's not about I have an error in this line. It's about how can I do this in an easy way? The steps, the line to follow for code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have done it following the advice of Jofre as he pointed in [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)
and looking in http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

**YOU MUST NOT MODIFY MANIFEST. DON'T ADD android:configChanges**

**SOLUTION:**

```
//ALL THE VARIABLES YOU NEED TO SAVE IN YOUR ADAPTER PUT THEM AS PUBLIC, IE: 
//public int a = 2;
//public String b = "a";

Public class Yourclass extends Activity{

Classofyouradapter adapter;

@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

    final Save_object data = (Save_object) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

    adapter = new Classofyouradapter(your variables);
    if (data != null) {
            fillit(data);
    }
    myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.yourpanelpager);    
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);    
}

@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    final Save_object data = new Save_object();
    return data;        
}

public class Save_object{
    int a = adapter.a;   
    String b = adapter.b;
    //Rest of variables
}

public void fillit(Save_object data){
    adapter.a= data.a;   
    adapter.b= data.b;          
    //Rest of variables 
}

}
```